# Advent of Code: Day 22 proof of correctness

Tags: python, algorithm, proof-of-correctness

This is part two of question 22:

```
Molecule fabrication always begins with just a single electron, e, and applying
replacements one at a time, just like the ones during calibration.

For example, suppose you have the following replacements:

e => H
e => O
H => HO
H => OH
O => HH

If you'd like to make HOH, you start with e, and then make the following
replacements:

e => O to get O
O => HH to get HH
H => OH (on the second H) to get HOH

So, you could make HOH after 3 steps. Santa's favorite molecule, HOHOHO,
can be made in 6 steps.

How long will it take to make the medicine? Given the available replacements and
the medicine molecule in your puzzle input, what is the fewest number of steps
to go from e to the medicine molecule?
```

And this was my Python 3 solution:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

transitions = defaultdict(list)
inv_transitions = dict()
endpoints = set()

with open('AC_Day-19.txt') as f:
    rules, string = f.read().split('\n\n')
    lines = rules.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        a, _, b = line.split()
        inv_transitions[b] = a

units = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]*')
tokens = units.findall(string)


temp_string = string
steps = 0
while True:
    if temp_string == "e":
        break
    for j in sorted(inv_transitions, key=len, reverse=True):
        if j in temp_string:
            temp_string = temp_string.replace(j, inv_transitions[j], 1)
            steps += 1
            break
        else:
            continue

print(steps)
```

Basically, after parsing the given data, the code continuously checks whether there is a match between the string and the inverse dictionary values, starting with the longest in each case, and replace with the corresponding values from the inverse dictionary.

I get the answer but I am not convinced. Is it possible to prove that this algorithm will always come up with the correct answer in any given setup?

(For example, can it not be the case that, for a given setup, the shortest route requires an intermediate step where we need to replace a shorter slice of the string when there is longer one available?

Or, could it not be the case that this approach gets stuck at some point, and we must take an intermediate step earlier? If so, how should I adjust the algorithm?)

Comment: I'm not very sure...but if you don't need the steps, isn't number of characters  the answer everytime if the target string can be reached? And, IMO all strings except more than 2 and all `H's` can be made.

Comment: Apparently this is [2015 day 19](https://shahata.github.io/adventofcode-solver/src/2015/day19.html), not "day 22" (year unclear)?